# How to select current item on hover with jQuery when all parents have the same class?

Tags: jquery, css

I've built a jsFiddle which recreates an issue I'm having with a layout built with a page builder plugin on my Wordpress site. There are five columns and all of them contain a photo album cover that has the same CSS class.

When I hover over the album covers I want a child div to appear through transitioning the opacity. When doing this with unordered lists, I've found that the hover pseudo class automatically selects the correct child, however the jQuery I've used behaves differently and selects all of the items with that same CSS class rather than just the child of the item I'm hovering over.

Is there a way I can get it to just effect the div I'm hovering over and it's children, rather than all of them?

https://jsfiddle.net/25pftxv3/

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="album-cover">
        <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="album-cover">
        <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="album-cover">
        <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="album-cover">
        <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="album-cover">
        <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>



html,
body {
  height:100%;
}

.column {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:18%;
  height:100%;
  margin:1%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.album-cover {
  padding:60px 0 !important;
  background:pink;
}

.album-cover-icon {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:yellow;
  opacity:0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.album-cover-icon.hover {
  opacity:1;
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

$(".album-cover").hover(function() {
    $(".album-cover-icon").addClass("hover");
}, function() {
    $(".album-cover-icon").removeClass("hover");
});

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.album-cover-icon` will target all `.album-cover-icon` elements.

You want to use `$(this).find('.album-cover-icon')` to target the `.album-cover-icon` in the currently hovered element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

$(".album-cover").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".album-cover-icon").addClass("hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".album-cover-icon").removeClass("hover");
});

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
}
.column {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:18%;
  height:100%;
  margin:1%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.album-cover {
  padding:60px 0 !important;
  background:pink;
}

.album-cover-icon {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:yellow;
  opacity:0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.album-cover-icon.hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But FYI, you can do this without JS/jQuery. Just use `:hover` on the parent to target the child.

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
}
.column {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:18%;
  height:100%;
  margin:1%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.album-cover {
  padding:60px 0 !important;
  background:pink;
}

.album-cover-icon {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:yellow;
  opacity:0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.album-cover:hover .album-cover-icon {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
  <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS only!  You beat me too it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've upvoted this as it's a great answer. I didn't know there was a CSS only solution. The only problem is that neither of them work on my website.. Here is the page I've used it on, can you see anything wrong with what I've done? The photo albums are at the bottom and for clarity's sake I've only semi-hidden the icons with opacity. When hovered over they should become fully opaque – http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work-3/

Comment: @Jack1991 add this `.et_divi_builder #et_builder_outer_content .et_pb_section .et_pb_row .et_pb_column .et_pb_module .album-cover:hover + .album-cover-icon-wrap, .et_divi_builder #et_builder_outer_content .et_pb_section .et_pb_row .et_pb_column .et_pb_module .album-cover-icon-wrap:hover { 
opacity: 1;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$(this)` to refer to the actual block being hovered on. Then use `.find()` to get it's child `.album-cover-icon`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".album-cover").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.album-cover-icon').addClass("hover");
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.album-cover-icon').removeClass("hover");
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.album-cover {
  padding: 60px 0 !important;
  background: pink;
}

.album-cover-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.album-cover-icon.hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <div class="album-cover-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cede to Michael Coker's answer though, as it's true you can just do this with CSS

Answer (score 1):

This short of it is that there are lots of ways.  My preferred favorite is using the context parameter of the jquery selector:

```
$( function(){ 
    $(".album-cover").hover(function() {
        $(".album-cover-icon", this).addClass("hover");
    }, function() {
        $(".album-cover-icon", this).removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

It will only match the selector to children of the second parameter (in the above example, `this`).

https://jsfiddle.net/u0Lrutrf/